# What does this self referencing code do?

Tags: common-lisp

What is this self reference for?

Could it be written in any other way?

Is there any advantage?

```
(defmacro sublet (bindings% &rest body)
  (let ((bindings (let-binding-transform
                    bindings%)))
    (setq bindings
      (mapcar
        (lambda (x)
          (cons (gensym (symbol-name (car x))) x))
        bindings))
    `(let (,@(mapcar #'list
                     (mapcar #'car bindings)
                     (mapcar #'caddr bindings)))
       ,@(tree-leaves
           body
           #1=(member x bindings :key #'cadr)
           (caar #1#)))))
```

Comment: Do you mean recursion, or am I just missing the self-reference?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I guess he's meaning the #1.

Comment: Can you show an example usage? A `macroexpand` on an example would be even better. And the definitions for `let-binding-transform` and `tree-leaves` might also be helpful to understand what is intended here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a way of reusing structure somewhere else. In the macro you have:

```
(tree-leaves body
             #1=(member x bindings :key #'cadr)
             (caar #1#))
```

Which is just a fancy way of writing:

```
(tree-leaves body
             (member x bindings :key #'cadr)
             (caar (member x bindings :key #'cadr)))
```

On the positive side if you correct a bug in the `member` form you'll fix it both places, but it's runs the same code twice so if `member` was expensive this wouldn't be the wise way to do it. However it is a macro, thus run at compile time, and `member` is fairly fast on mall lists (small == millions of elements or below) so I guess it won't matter if you read the references just as good as any other CL code. An alternative and perhaps more readable for other kind of lispers would be:

```
(let ((found (member x bindings :key #'cadr)))
  (tree-leaves body found (caar found)))
```

Comment: So the code would run twice? In a way, it's similar to writing the same thing twice, since it would run twice, also. Correct?

Comment: @EuAndré correct. It's just a compression in writing, not in execution.